# Foreach input array param then save 1 record per element in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, carrierwave

i'm making a form to upload multiple images with carrierwave. Save array to db work fine but i want to save 1 array element as 1 record, to make it easier to manage later. 
I tried to do as below but it return nilClass err.

All picture use the same description, name is image file name

Anyone has done this kind of stuff before :'(

***views/_form***

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @picture], :html => {multipart: true, :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
<div class="box-body">

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :link, :class => 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= f.file_field :link, multiple: true, :class => 'form-control', :id => 'imgInp' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :description, :class => 'control-label col-sm-2' %>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <%= f.text_area :description, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
  <div class="box-footer">
    <%= link_to admin_pictures_path do %>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-info pull-right' %>
</div>
<!-- /.box-footer -->    <% end %>
```

***controller***

```
def create

    if params[:link]
    params[:link].each { |image|
      @picture = Picture.new(name: image.file.filename, description: params[:description], link: image)
      @picture.save
    }
    end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
    if @picture.save
      format.html { redirect_to admin_pictures_path, notice: ' picture was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @picture }
else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end
end
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_picture
  @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white  list through.
def picture_params
  params.require(:picture).permit(:name, :description, :link)
end
end
```

***param[:link] console***

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"2KMy3lPMnf3MqLLHpJAH+Ei40nja+KAJGsx2twyP5L05A95b7rLsZHEFoUSu+CMJQunQ4yUq6kmppdK6I7NQkw==", 
"picture"=>{"album_id"=>"3", "team_id"=>"", "link"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9095ea1c08 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160331-6776-1h8i98y.jpg>, 
@original_filename="images.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[link][]\"; 
filename=\"images.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9095ea1be0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160331-6776-y6d6ug.jpg>, @original_filename="images (1).jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[link][]\"; 
filename=\"images (1).jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9095ea1bb8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160331-6776-hizrku.jpg>, 
@original_filename="lulu.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture[link][]\"; 
filename=\"lulu.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">], 
"description"=>"abc"}, "commit"=>"Create Picture"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
params: 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the `params.inspect` hash from console ?

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli: er? how should i type that? I'm a newbie

Comment: In your `create` method add puts "params: #{params[:link]}" on first line & submit your form then in console copy the `puts` result and paste in the question.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli updated Q

Comment: I think the `@update` at **@update.save** is nil, because above your code, you already had saved the date, I suggest you to create detail table of your users where you will put the images.

Comment: @Lymuel i tried the answer below but  error still persisted. it seems if params statement not working

Comment: huhm, i removed if and it said params[:link] is nil. so weird. why it not pass the param? @MuhammadYawarAli

Comment: @Okami Actually, its `params[:picture][:link]` not `params[:link]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your issue :

```
def create
    if params[:picture][:link]
    params[:picture][:link].each { |image|
      @picture = Picture.new(:name => image.original_filename,:description => params[:description])
      @picture.store!(image.tempfile)
      @picture.save
    }
    end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
    if @picture.save
      format.html { redirect_to admin_pictures_path, notice: ' picture was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @picture }
else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: it gives me 'undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass' at respond format @picture.save

Comment: Answer updated try now. or add this `@picture.store!(File.open(image.tempfile.path))`

Comment: same error, seem like it not go in if statement. add a puts but console not return

Comment: cool, if statement works. but i got another error 'undefined method `store!''

Comment: also how could i get the filename?

Comment: yes you can get filename by : `image.original_filename` and which gem you are using for image saving ?

Comment: in my case i have this  `mount_uploader :file, UserUploader` in my `User` model so i am saving file as : `@user.file.store!(image.tempfile)` edit store statement as per your model details.

Comment: yay, it works =)). thanks so much. but link value is 'RackMultipart20160331-11152-1sqljt2.jpg' (temp name). seem not right. image_tag did not show anything

Comment: fixed it by myself. i understood alot, tks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
...
@picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
respond_to do |format|
    if @picture.save...
```

so that **@picture.save** will not result to **nil**

Comment: the default is working fine, but it gonna store a lot of link as array in 1 record. I dont want that

Comment: Just like what I've said create a detail table for your picture

Comment: i created it at first. it have 6 column: id, name, desc, link, created_at, updated_at